# DesignerHost fails to create control with Visible = false

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

Good day!

I'm writing a .vsix to replace old controls to new ones. I have designerHost which is the current designer instance. Then I start converting like this:

```
 foreach (OldCombo oldCmbx in OldCmbxs())
 {
      ...
      NewCombo newCmbx = designerHost.CreateComponent(NewComboType, oldcmbx.Name) as NewCmbx;
      ...
      newCmbx.Visible = oldCmbx.Visible;
      ...
      designerHost.DestroyComponent(oldCmbx);
 }
```

The thing is `-oldCmbx` is always `Visible=true`, no matter how it's written in the designer.cs file. I'm always creating `Visible=true` newCmbx's. If I force newCmbx to be `Visible=false`, then designer doesn't show newCmbx after the conversion, but the visible property is still true, so Visible property is definitely not what I'm searching for. So how can I force newCmbx's to be `Visible=false` in designer.cs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging through .NET source code I've found that `ControlDesigner` is shadowing `Visible` property of the `Control`, so what is going to be serialized/deserialized in `InitializeComponent` is far related from actual `Visible` property of Control.

`Designer.Visible` property is initialized like this:

```
public override void Initialize(IComponent component)
{
   PropertyDescriptorCollection properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(component.GetType());
   PropertyDescriptor descriptor = properties["Visible"];
   if (((descriptor == null) || (descriptor.PropertyType != typeof(bool))) || !descriptor.ShouldSerializeValue(component))
    {
        this.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        this.Visible = (bool) descriptor.GetValue(component);
    }
    ...
 }
```

`descriptor.ShouldSerializeValue(component)` for `Control.Visible` is always `false` in case of newly created control.

`Designer.Visible` property:

```
private bool Visible
{
    get
    {
        return (bool) base.ShadowProperties["Visible"];
    }
    set
    {
        base.ShadowProperties["Visible"] = value;
    }
}
```

In the `Designer.PreFilterProperties()` actual `Visible` property of the `Control` is shadowed by `Visible` property of the designer.

Now, when the designer is initialized(in my code that's happening when I'm creating component `designerHost.CreateComponent`) `newCmbx.Visible` is always `true`.

Why it is so? Because `Visible` property of the `Control` is used in painting of the control(on the designer surface as well). If I set `newCmbx.Visible = false` it just disappears from the design surface (but still serializes from the `Visible` property of the designer) - that's bad, so by design of the `Control` class, when `Control` is instantiated, it is always `Visible` so that it could be visible on the design surface. Any subsequent changes in `Visible` property influence `Visible` property of the designer, not Control itself (in the context of working in Designer mode).

So, what I need in order to solve that problem is `Visible` property of the designer.

Correct code looks like this:

```
foreach (OldCombo oldCmbx in OldCmbxs())
{
  bool _visible = GetVisiblePropThroughReflection(designerHost.GetDesigner(oldCmbx));
  ...
  NewCombo newCmbx = designerHost.CreateComponent(NewComboType, oldcmbx.Name) as NewCmbx;
  ...
  SetVisiblePropThroughReflection(designerHost.GetDesigner(newCmbx), _visible);
  ...
  designerHost.DestroyComponent(oldCmbx);
}
```